# what is asm stand for in linux/include/asm

Tags: linux

read from [howto_add_systemcall](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/undergraduate/CMSC421/fall02/burt/projects/howto_add_systemcall.html)

> "In general, header files for machine architecture independent system
>   calls and functions are kept under linux/include/linux/ and machine
>   architecture dependent ones are kept in linux/include/asm/"

so what does asm stand for here?

I've searched wiki, but not found the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess it stands for Architecture Specific Macros (asm) initially. 
After that, any architecture specific stuff are placed there.

Answer (score 4):

"asm" stands for "assembler" or ["assembly language"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language).

Comment: but the files in asm directory are not write in assembler

Comment: @AylwynLake I think it's a historical artifact. Much of the "architecture specific" information is collected in directories called "asm", despite it mostly just being header files. I believe that this came about simply because much architecture specific code was assembler traditionally, and the directory name stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Assembly code for handling system calls for x86 architecture are located at,

```
arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S (or _64.S)
```